# Button click - navigate do different component angular

Tags: html, angular, scroll, angular-material

So here's a snippet of my page [snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4C9C.png)

and as you can see I've got my toolbar with little cute buttons

I'm trying to navigate to sections of my page by clicking on those buttons
(clicking on about me should scroll down to the start of the section About Me)
and I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

I'll post below the toolbar and about me components, as well as the app.component.html file.

toolbar.html:

```
<mat-toolbar class="example-toolbar">
  <span style="margin-left: 120px; height: 40px">Jane Doe</span>
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>

  <div>

    <button mat-button >
      About
    </button>
....
```

(the rest is just the same button tags but for the other stuff)

about-me.component.html:

```
<div class="main-div" id="abme">
  <mat-card class="example-card shadow">
    <mat-card-content>
      <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="50%">

          <p class="title">About me</p>
          <br>

          <p class="about-me-content" style="font-size: 16px">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ac quam augue tempor blandit et sit amet mi.
            Donec fringilla dictum tellus, sed porttitor diam. In tempus turpis quis aliquet efficitur.
            Proin auctor lacus rhoncus ultrices hendrerit. Sed eu aliquet metus, vulputate lacinia ex. <br>
            <br> Nulla venenatis nulla nec tellus convallis iaculis id hendrerit nibh. Pellentesque sed eleifend diam.
            Suspendisse nec rhoncus augue, id pellentesque sem. Nullam pellentesque ipsum ut dignissim semper.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="50%" style="padding-left: 150px">
        // then in this column are the icons, i believe irrelevant to this problem

      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

and app.component.html:

```
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
<br>
<app-cover-card></app-cover-card>
<br><br>
<app-about-me style="padding: 30px"></app-about-me>
<br><br>
<app-professional-skills style="padding: 40px"  ></app-professional-skills>
```

The .ts files are just as they were generated, I've not changed a thing inside them.
Any suggestions/useful links would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `scrollIntoView()` to scroll around pages. Give the correct element id of the page in the `ts` file to navigate.

toolbar.html:

```
<button mat-button (click)="navigateSection()">
      About
</button>
```

toolbar.ts:

```
 navigateSection(): any {
    const element = document.getElementById('abme') as HTMLElement;
    element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'});
 }
```

Here when the about button clicks it smoothly navigates to the about section in the page.

Answer (score 0):

use routerLink attribute

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button color="warn" routerLink="/component">
```